# ClassCastException to comparable

Tags: java, path-finding

i'm making a school project wehere we have to implement the A* algorithm to solthe the 8-puzzle problem. When creating a Node and adding it to the queue, there is no problem, but when I create a second one, and try to add it to the queue, it can't compate them both, to check wich has the lowest f-cost.

```
private class Node implements Comparable<Node>{
    private Node parent;
    private int distance;
    private int moves;
    private Board board;

    public Node(Node parent, Board board, int moves) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.board = board;
        this.moves = moves;
        distance = board.manhattan();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node node) {
        return this.moves + this.distance - node.moves - node.distance;
    }
}
```

this is the class where I create my Node's.
Now when trying to test if this works, I created a slamm JUnit test to see if it would work, but I get the error that my Node class cannot be cast to a comparable.
Here is the code of the test I'm trying to run:

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import org.junit.Test;    

public class UnitTests {
private PriorityQueue<Node> closedPQ =  new PriorityQueue<Node>();
@Test
public void pqTest() {
    int N = 3, counter = 1;
    int[][] tiles = new int[N][N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            tiles[i][j] = counter++;
        }
    }
    tiles[2][2] = 0;
    tiles[1][1] = 6;
    tiles[1][2] = 5;

    Board initial = new Board(tiles);

    tiles[1][1] = 5;
    tiles[1][2] = 6;

    Board initial2 = new Board(tiles);

 System.out.println(initial.manhattan());
 System.out.println(initial2.manhattan());

 closedPQ.add(new Node(null, initial, 0));
 closedPQ.add(new Node(null, initial2, 0));

 Node n = closedPQ.remove();
 System.out.println(n.distance);
}
}
```

First u just make a new board, and then change some nubers to get different costs. The error i get is when I try to add the second Node to the PQ. Anyone got an idea of how to fix this? I'm expecting that the Node with the smallest f ost is returned to me at the remove operation. This is the second Node I add to the queue, because its manhatten-score is 0, while the firsts Node's board has a manhatten-score of 0.

The Failure trace I get is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: gna.UnitTests$Node cannot be cast to   java.lang.Comparable
at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUpComparable(Unknown Source)
at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUp(Unknown Source)
at java.util.PriorityQueue.offer(Unknown Source)
at java.util.PriorityQueue.add(Unknown Source)
at gna.UnitTests.pqTest(UnitTests.java:100)
```

Comment: Post a stacktrace.

Comment: Do you mean a Failure Trace? edited it in

Comment: It doesn't help that we can't see the declaration of `closedPQ`. Please add a [mcve] rather than just snippets. (Hint: with the exception you're getting, none of the board parts are actually relevant...)

Comment: This still isn't a [mcve]. We want to be able to copy, paste, compile and run. It sounds like either you're using the wrong `Node` class, or something else odd is going on. Is the `Node` class you've shown us really a nested type in `UnitTests`?

Comment: The Node class is officialy in my Solver.java, but took it and out it in my UnitTests, and okay, now I got what you want, i'm on it!

Comment: Some addition: your junit test tests nothing. JUnit provides several static methods to assert your actual results with expected. See [this](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html).

Comment: And could you please provide full sources (with `package` statements)?

Comment: I've found the problem! Thanks anyway!